# Can I carry homeopathic medicines and uncooked rice to Germany?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, health, food-and-drink

I am traveling from India to Celle, Germany. I am used to Indian cuisine.

Can I carry homeopathic medicines and uncooked rice to Germany?

Is there something specifically I need to carry like spices?

Is it fine if we get woolens from there (probably at the same Indian price)?

Comment: If I may guide you: Always take a towel with you.

Comment: But seriously: Your question, at least the second part, is too broad. Asking if you can take certain medicaments with you is a nice question. Asking (seperately) if bringing cooked rice with you is also a good question. However, asking for guidance does not really fit the purpose of this site. You should also add where you're travelling from as that might change the answer.

Comment: Rice is obviously available in Germany (but not necessarily all types of rice you might be used to find at home).

Comment: @Relaxed I believe that the OP is Indian due to both those items being very common in India. Basmati Rice is the rice in question here I believe, it is truly special, try it in India once, you won't be disappointed.

Comment: @AdityaSomani I can find Basmati rice (and a few other premium rices) in my local supermarket and I do like it ;-) I don't know how it compares with Basmati rice in India, though.

Comment: Curious: http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/cms_ia/importalert_1.html

Comment: Not sure why there is a concern about importation of rice: http://www.basmatirice.de/index.php?pid=1

Comment: Since Homeopatic medicine is technically water or an alcolholic beverage with an unlimited diluted substance, of which there is no detection method, your fine as long as you respect the alcohol import rules. (i.e. 2 liters)

Comment: I once carried 23kg of "mici" - Romanian meat delicacy - with a friend.

Comment: @Relaxed I can find it in the US too, but maybe the OP insists on rice from India. In their defense it does taste different. :/

Comment: Since this is just water and uncooked rice (both of wich are sold freely in Germany), sure!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you could be pleasantly surprised to find actually good indian restaurants, run by actual indians, in at least the major german cities. When I lived in Hamburg, I had two wonderful indian restaurants within walking distance, both of which were certainly able to provide you with a proper indian dish. You may want to specifically say that the spice level should be "indian", which is typically above "hot" in the european scale ("how you want it? mild, spicy, hot or indian?")

Answer (score 51):

Unlike [meat products and potatoes](http://www.zoll.de/DE/Privatpersonen/Reisen/Reisen-nach-Deutschland/Einschraenkungen/Lebensmittel-und-Futtermittel/lebensmittel-und-futtermittel_node.html), grains like rice can be brought into Germany.

Homeopathic remedies are not considered medicines in Germany, because their efficacy has not been proven. Legally, it's just sugar or alcohol, and unless you bring ridiculous amounts, you will not exceed the free import limit for alcohol.

Finally, there is a limit on the [total value of goods](http://www.zoll.de/DE/Privatpersonen/Reisen/Reisen-nach-Deutschland/Zoll-und-Steuern/Reisefreimengen/reisefreimengen_node.html) which you can bring with you, which is 430 EUR for air travellers.

Comment: Will the total value of the goods be assessed on what a believer in homeopathy would pay for them, or the German government's official position that it's just water and basically free?

Comment: @SteveJessop That value is *purchase price* or equivalent value. So, the first of your options would be the correct one. Note that goods is just goods, not personal stuff.

Comment: downvoted since it sounds offensive for the original questioner; instead of focusing on the main subject, it criticizes homeopathy and the user's beliefs and treatments in a way not needed and completely unrelated to the main subject.

Comment: Upvoted for pointing out that Homeopathic remedies are not medicine (and to counter-balance Igoru's knee-jerk downvote).

Comment: Doesn't matter what anyone believes but the German government. They set the rules. So if they decide it's not medicine, then for custom reasons it is not. The notion is called a "legal fiction".

Comment: While I regard homeopathy as undiluted nonsense, homeopathic medicines aren't exactly seen as the same as water. See [Regulation of homeopathy in Germany](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_and_prevalence_of_homeopathy#Germany). As a side note, I've heard that some products marketed as "homeopathic" have components other than alcohol or water at non-negligible concentrations, some of which may be harmful. But up voting to counter the downvote anyway.

Comment: Question on Skeptics.SE, where some people note that products marketed as "homeopathic" can contain active ingredients: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/100/104

Comment: Real homeopathic "medicines" are as Michael says, but lots of "homeopathic" medicines are not actually homeopathic or their makers would lose all their customers as soon as the customers notice no effectiveness. Instead, they often contain unlabeled active ingredients that make them work: things like high doses of zinc (cold remedies, etc.), steroids, or even (on the more extreme end) viagra.

Answer (score 5):

I personally have carried these these items from India to Sweden through Germany multiple times without any problems whatsoever. You should be fine. As Michael has already pointed out, these are not restricted items. Not that anyone bothers to check.

Comment: Thanks..I am travelling from India to celle.Can u plz guide on what to take and what not to take. Can u please give some insights..