# Rice in check in baggage

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, check-in, manila

I am an Indian citizen, travelling from Chennai to Manila. Can I bring 20kgs of rice in check in baggage to Manila .
Do I get any problem in customs.

Comment: Why? I'm pretty sure you can buy all the rice you want in Manila...

Comment: Yes, you are likely to get problems in customs, but we lack details to be sure. Does your rice have an export certificate?

Comment: Even if it was perfectly legal, 20 kg of rice will probably cause a lot of searching and questioning. The authorities might think you're hiding something illegal in it.

Comment: [Why](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/140705/47309) [are](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/133282/47309) [so](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/135609/47309) [many](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/142386/47309) [people](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31267/47309) [carrying](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76847/47309) [rice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/102591/47309) in their [luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/131501/47309)?

Comment: The import limit for personal use appears to be 10kg; if the rice is unprocessed, it is not allowed at all. https://www.philippine-embassy.org.sg/travel-advisories/bringing-regulated-products-for-personal-use-into-the-philippines/

Comment: @shoover Based on my cursory search, it's mostly Indians. Which is funny, because there are Indian expat communities almost everywhere, getting Indian food ingredients abroad has never been easier and vegetarian food is also not a scarcity (apart from maybe rural Eastern Europe). Not to mention one should also try different cuisines when travelling!

Comment: Context: India banned export of non-basmati rice. We are used to local variety of Indian rice and can't easily adjust to other ones. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-66360064

Comment: I understand, but by sticking to known food all over the globe one deprives themselves of all sorts of experiences. Imagine an Italian travelling to Japan and only eating there in pizzerias for two weeks. Crazy, isn't it? But some people do just that...